# Hoare Triple Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-logic, formal-methods, hoare-logic

I'm having trouble understanding the logic behind Hoare Triples. The question asks for the missing value of the precondition {X}

```
{X}  
if (b mod 2 <> 0)
      t = 1
else
      t = 0
{t = b – 2*(b div 2)}
```

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: The answer depends on the exact semantics of the operations `mod` and `div`. You might get away with the empty precondition (which always holds).

Comment: Maybe consider what would make the program crash. Usually preconditions are needed to block that.